# Sum the elements of each element of an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array

```
[array([  2.46000000e-02,   4.28211000e+01,   7.95400000e+00]), array([  0.0987,  15.1704,   7.5235]), array([ 0.2502,  7.5852,  0.041 ])]
```

I am finding the the sum of the items in the array rows
for item in acb which the array above:

```
for item in acb:
   print    sum(item) 



50.7997
22.7926
7.8764
```

I would like to generate an array with above numbers 50.799,22.79,7.87

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the sum of a single array? Just do it in a loop or an array comprehension.

Comment: `sum(itertools.chain(list_of_arrays))`

Comment: thanks i just want to get an array back  somearray[50.79,etc]

Comment: Are you using numpy arrays or are these actually lists?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have your arrays as an multidimensional numpy array you can use `np.sum()` in order to get the sum of the items over second axis:

```
>>> A = [np.array([  2.46000000e-02,   4.28211000e+01,   7.95400000e+00]), np.array([  0.0987,  15.1704,   7.5235]), np.array([ 0.2502,  7.5852,  0.041 ])]
>>> A = np.array(A)
>>> 
>>> np.sum(A, axis=1)
array([ 50.7997,  22.7926,   7.8764])
```

Note that this would be more efficient if you are dealing with large data sets, otherwise you can simply use `map()` function to get the sum of all arrays in a list (in python3 an iterator).

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert that loop into a list comprehension:

```
>>> [sum(item) for item in acb]
[50.799700000000001, 22.7926, 7.8764000000000003]
```

If you want a `numpy.array`, either convert the result accordingly...

```
>>> np.array(_)
array([ 50.7997,  22.7926,   7.8764])
```

... or use [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) with `axis` parameter:

```
>>> np.sum(acb, axis=1)
array([ 50.7997,  22.7926,   7.8764])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
np.array([sum(i) for i in acb])
```

test:

```
In [71]: np.array([sum(i) for i in acb])
Out[71]: array([ 50.7997,  22.7926,   7.8764])
```

or as it's already has been mentioned just:

```
In [72]: np.sum(acb, axis=1)
Out[72]: array([ 50.7997,  22.7926,   7.8764])
```

this will most probably be faster